# Can't reach device through multiple routers

Tags: routing, router

I have the following construct:

> (WEB)
>             |
>     Router(Fritz Box)
>      **192.168.178.1**
>           /              \
>   Router           <kbd>PC **192.168.178.34**</kbd>
>   (Asus WLan)
>   **192.168.1.1**
>         |
> <kbd>destination device **192.168.1.43**</kbd>

Now I want to reach the specific destination device with the PC. How can I configure the routers, that i can communicate to this device. I dont know if Routing Tables are related.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Fritz Box but if it isn't automatically building those routes for you you need to add a static route to your Asus WLAN.

Some thing to the effect of

Network= 192.168.1.0/24 Gateway=192.168.1.1

in the Fritz and set the default gateway of the Asus box to 192.168.178.1.

http://en.avm.de/nc/service/fritzbox/fritzbox-7390/knowledge-base/publication/show/581_Configuring-a-static-IP-route-in-the-FRITZ-Box/